# Is there any website to upload/edit source code?

Tags: website

I really like [PBworks](http://pbworks.com/) but when I hit 'formatted' and paste my code (no other setting keeps single lines single) the spaces get messed up so it looks weird when I paste it back. (Luckily I don't write Python code.)

What site can I use to write (copy/paste) code and edit it repeatedly?

Answer (score 6):

The first thing that comes to mind is [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com). I have not had problems with copying and pasting back to applications and it supports syntax highlighting of many different languages.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [CodePaste.NET](http://codepaste.net/) .

It's a great site for code help, etc. Does formatting for you. Made by [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/default.aspx) who's well known in the .NET geek circles.

Comment: This looks like it does what i want. No privacy but it copy/paste and edits well :D

Comment: Enojy :) It's a great little site :)

Answer (score 2):

[Pastie](http://pastie.org/) is another good pastebin type site. It has the dubious advantage of defaulting to a dark color scheme. It also seems to load a tad faster than Pastebin for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use [**CodePad**](http://codepad.org), the benefit being that you can run your code on their server if they support the language. You can't directly edit a paste, but you can fork it and make a new one. Syntax highlighting and all the regular fixings are supported, you can even register an account to keep track of your code if you wish. There is also [**ASCIIbin**](http://www.asciibin.com/) and [**Mozilla's Bespin**](https://bespin.mozilla.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript (and HTML/CSS), including actual execution for live testing of the code (in your own browser, of course, but not in IE6), there's the brilliant [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Be sure to watch the short [introduction videos](http://jsbin.com/about). Once you saved your code to a public URL it cannot be changed, but others can save their changes and then get a brand new URL they can paste in a forum or on sites like Super User.

Minor annoyance: it embeds Google Analytics tracking code (but only when running from the bare URL), which may interfere in some rare cases (like when trying to figure out if [Is $(document).ready() also CSS ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324568/is-document-ready-also-css-ready/1324720#1324720)).

Answer (score 1):

There are only two *I* know of that let you update your snippets. These are, consequently, the only two I use:

- [Snipplr](http://snipplr.com/)
- [Refactor :my => 'code'](http://refactormycode.com/)

**Snipplr** is cool and has an API, and a textmate bundle. **Refactor :my => 'code'** is cool because it's main purpose is to get advice from other people about how to optimize your snippets, but it can double as a personal snippet repo in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another pastebin with quite a lot of features and formating options: [Friendpaste](http://friendpaste.com)

Answer (score 0):

[Gist](https://gist.github.com) - a part of [GitHub](https://github.com/)

- Syntax highlighting or view as raw text
- can do sets of files as well as individual files
- version controlled
- embeddable in blogs
- download files in tar.gz